# Calculating the slope for parts of the dem

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.2

In my PostGIS / PostgreSQL DB I have a DEM cropped to the size of Germany. As a second (vector) layer I have 1300 catchment areas (<30km²) for which I want to calculate the slope. To reduce the calculation time and effort I decided to clip the DEM to the geometries of the catchment and calculate their slope values afterwards. The DEM has to be transformed to SRID 31467.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS spatial_derived.ezg_slope;
CREATE TABLE spatial_derived.ezg_slope AS

SELECT gid rid, ST_Union(rast) rast
FROM (
SELECT ezg.gid,
ST_slope(ST_Clip(ST_Transform(eu.rast, 31467), ezg.geom, -9999, true),1,'32BF','degree',1,false) rast
FROM spatial_derived.land_use_ezg30 ezg, spatial.eu_dem eu
WHERE ST_Intersects(eu.rast, ezg.geom) AND ST_IsValid(ezg.geom) )t1
GROUP BY gid
```

This worked nicely for a LIMIT of 20 rows:

[image]

However when I try to apply the query on all the data I just get an area of the size of the bounding box with 0s, and the polygons are not presented anymore. Up to now I can't go into more detail what might have gone wrong. 
My question here is if the query contains any evident flaws?

Comment: Is your raster tiled? Why do you have to ST_Union() pieces together?

Comment: I changed my query. I'm not sure if it's tiles (since there are no real tiles in PostGIS?), but there are multiple rows. I want to union the **rast** rows which are overlaped by the same polygon.

Comment: What happens if you don't use the ST_Union? It might be that you have a very big polygon that kills of the rest of the output. In the ST_Union, the last raster defines the pixel value when there is overlap, so your first 20 results might be overridden by one last failing raster.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I don't have a big polygon at the end (apart from PostGIS creating one when executing this code?) and I use ST_Union because otherwise I have some strange lines in the rasters. I can try it tomorrow.
BTW: In the end I used GDAL to do this calculation, which doesn't mean I'm not interested in solving it with PostGIS anymore..